# Polling if I can PUSH or send in zmq?

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

By using 0mq, I am trying to detect if I have made a successful connection to a PULL port, and if I can PUSH. However, it didn't work as I had expected, see the example code below. Poller will return immediately even remote peer hasn't been started to accept connections. Is there a way to fix it?

```
import sys
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
pusher = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
pusher.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")
poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(pusher, zmq.POLLOUT)
socks = dict(poller.poll(timeout=1000))

if pusher in socks and socks[pusher] == zmq.POLLOUT:
    print("Pusher can push")
else:
    print("Failed to connect, exit.")
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be allowed to send as long as you haven't reached the High Water Mark ( HWM ) of the sending socket - the number of messages allowed to pile up on the sender side.

By default it is set to 1000 as far as I remember.

/Søren